# Best way to handle images when updating graphics Javascript

Tags: javascript, storage, nlp-question-answering

So in this project that I am writing i have a wheel that contains of images. They are drawn with the **canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage()** function. My first idea was that I would just get the img in the loop as the following.

```
while(wheel){

    //all other code ^^        

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = getImgFromKeyword(passedLocations[i].keyword); //Will return a URL to an image
    var x = Math.cos(dp/2 + dp * i ) * (pr -  startPosInSlice) - imgsize/2;
    var y = Math.sin(dp/2 + dp * i ) * (pr - startPosInSlice) - imgsize/2;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, imgsize, imgsize);
}
```

However since i am running this in a loop I am actually loading that URL litteraly THOUSANDS of Thousands of time. I reckon that this will be rather insufficient to the runtime. Would storing the images in an array upon initialize and then refer to that object in the drawing be more efficient.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't redeclare `imageObj` every time, so you need to put this outside your loop. It's also useless to reset the `src` property every time, so this would be the best way:

```
let imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = // load url
while (wheel) {
  // draw your stuff
}
```